# Unable to draw Unicode chars whose value is > 0xFFFF in Flex

Tags: apache-flex

I'm trying to draw a character from a Unicode font whose value is 0x1d11e (this is the treble clef character from the Sonata font).

I read on an [Adobe forum](http://forums.adobe.com/) that I have to convert Unicode chars > 0xFFFF to using UTF-16 surrogate pairs, but this doesn't seem to work.

Here's my code:

```
[Embed(source='C:/WINDOWS/Fonts/SonataStd.otf',
  fontName="Sonata__", mimeType="application/x-font")]
private var font1:Class;


public function draw():void {
  var txt:TextField = new TextField();
  var fmt:TextFormat = new TextFormat("Sonata__", 40);
  var clefChar:uint = 0x1d11e

  var p1:uint = (((clefChar - 0x10000) >> 10) & 0x3ff) + 0xd800;
  var p2:uint = ((clefChar - 0x10000) & 0x3ff ) + 0xdc00;


  txt.text = String.fromCharCode(p1, p2);


  txt.setTextFormat(fmt);
  txt.embedFonts = true;
  addChild(txt);
```

When I run this code nothing gets drawn. If I try drawing a 2-byte Unicode char it works.

This is on Flex 3, running on Flash Player 10.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Big unicode problems - AS3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17957569/big-unicode-problems-as3)